# How to do urlconf in django 2.0+

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-urls

I have created a view at `example.views.py`, and here is my urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('/', example.views.index, name='index'),
]
```

However, when I run django's runserver, I get the following error:

```
path('/', example.views.index, name='index'),
NameError: name 'example' is not defined
```

What do I need to do to fix this? Quoting the view doesn't help either.

Comment: You need to add ` from example import views` at top of your file and use `views.index` inside path function. Would this work?

Comment: You probably don’t want `path('/', ...)`. You don’t need the leading slash, so to match the root url `/` you want `path('', ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it to:

```
from django.urls import path
from example import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('/', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: thanks, that seems so odd though, what if I have 10 apps I want to import here, would I have to alias each of those views?

Comment: Well, you would have a master urls.py file (in your project), which would include the urls.py files from each app. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs